# Broadcast Receiver not receiving the the message after Boot/Reboot on Oneplus devices

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, mi

[image]

OnePlus devices need the Auto Launch permission to get it work but I didn't get any way to navigate to that permission in App Info.
Also tried the

> com.oneplus.security.chainlaunch.view.ChainLaunchAppListActivity >

This again doesn't work for me.
For MI devices their Intent is working to turn on AutoStart but facing issues in OnePlus Devices.